# Refreshing data using AJAX in ASP masterpage

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webforms

I have some processes that run as a background job, allowing a user to continue to use a page, when the jobs are finished (which can take a few minutes) i want to display a message to the user, the best place to display this would be the masterpage AFAIK (incase they move from page to page on the site) so i have defined a div in the masterpage file.

I am trying to find the best method for displaying the data, at the moment i have a method in the masterpage vb file which polls a database to see if the job(which involves complex logic and some db access) has completed, if it has, it shows a message in the div e.g. "Job 13132 has completed" - which works fine.

The problem is this is not dynamic, and i have to refresh the page to call the function that checks if the processes have finished, how can i use AJAX to deliver this content automatically every 5 seconds?

I have tried using an asp timer with a 5 second tick time but the entire page refreshes on the timer click event every 5 seconds.

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(Byval sender as Object, Byval e As EventArgs)
    poll_results()
End Sub

Public Sub poll_results()

 'database access logic 

 If dbtable.isCompleted = True
     Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
     sb.Append("$('#status').html('Job abc123 is complete');")
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "myscript", sb.ToString(), True)
 End If

End Sub
```

Is there a way to only refresh the div with the updated message, without a full refresh happening using this code? Or if this is not possible, is there any way to replicate the above function using jQuery and still be able to update the DIV text only if a job as finished?

Comment: you mention ASP Masterpage, but you tagged `ASP.NET`, is this an `ASP.NET Webforms` project?

Comment: Hi, Yes this is an asp.net webforms based project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily go throw what we called, an **async call**, instead calling your method in the same page, just create an `async` folder in your website and add a new **Generic Handler**, call the page, for example `checkPendingJobs.ashx`.

in that page, add your current method:

```vb
Public Sub ProcessRequest (Byval context as HttpContext)

    Dim r As String = ""

    If dbtable.isCompleted = True
       Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
       r = "Job abc123 is complete"
    End If     

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    context.Response.Write(r)
}
```

Now that you did your **Server part**, let's do the client part, in your page, add this *jQuery* code to tour masterpage, witch will fire every time some one refreshes the page, or you can use `setInterval()` to check it every xx seconds:

```js
<script>

var checkJobs = true;

$(document).ready(function() {

    // every time someone refreshes the page
    checkPendingJobs();

    // every 5 seconds...
  setInterval(function(){ checkPendingJobs(); }, 5000);

});

function checkPendingJobs() {
    // no need to check it if we already have a valid response
    if(!checkJobs) return;

    // caching issue trick
    var now = new Date(); 

    $.ajax({
        url: "../async/checkPendingJobs.ashx",
        type: "GET",
        data: { t: now.getTime() },
        success: function(data) {

            // do we have text to show?
            if(data.length > 0) {
                alert(data);
                checkJobs = false; // no need to check it more...
                // $('#status').html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert('Error found:\n' + msg);
        }
    });        
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for posting this code, sorry to be a pain but i have copied and pasted this in, just to test before making any changes, but i am getting the following error in the javascript error console..

    Error: missing } after property list - LINE =>  success: function(data) {      I can't see anything missing but haven't done this before so can't be sure if there is something i need to add?

Comment: there is one `}` missing to close the `.ajax()` call, as well a comma `,` ... sorry about that, code was edited in the answer, you can safely copy/paste, and please test the VB code, so many years in C# that I forgot the basics in VB :o(

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach to this would be to create a single page that will render out either JSON or HTML. This of this as the "poll_results" method, think of it as poll_result.aspx. You can either pass a single Job ID to this page or just do a poll for any jobs that have finished since the last polling.

Your Masterpage will have a snipet of JavaScript that will use a timer (client side javascript timer) to send an AJAX request to the server, hitting your "poll_request.aspx" page. This page will return either HTML or JSON and you will write some JavaScript to show your message. If you need some code samples let me know.